# Insert Google Adsense after 3rd paragraph

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-ads-api, adsense

I am trying to work out, in nextjs (reacts) how would I insert a Google Adsense after say the 3 paragraph in the article?

basically we embed the content like this

```
 <Card.Body dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data.news.content }}>
```

And somehow I want to after it is loaded to check how many paragraph and insert the ad after say 3 paragraphs.

Comment: did you find the solution? If yes, please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to do the above I implemented the following.

```
  // This also gets called at build time
  export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {
   
    const res = await fetch(`https://APIDOMAIN.com.au/api-access/news/${params.slug}`)
    const data = await res.json()
    const currentU  = `https://APIDOMIAN.com.au/news/${params.slug}`
     
    if (!data.news || data.news == "null") {
      return {
        notFound: true,
      }
    }


    let paraStr = data.news.content
    let paraArray = paraStr.split("</p>")
    console.log(paraArray);
    let NewsContentText ="";
    paraArray.forEach(myFunction);
    
    function myFunction(item, index) {
   
      if (index & 1){
        NewsContentText += item + '<br> <ins class="adsbygoogle"        style="display:block; text-align:center;"    data-ad-layout="in-article"        data-ad-format="fluid"    data-ad-client="ca-pub-(Google_AD_ID)"    data-ad-slot="(GOOGLEID)"></ins><br>'; 
        }else{
          NewsContentText += item; 
        }
    }
    // Pass post data to the page via props
    return { props: { data,NewsContentText, currentU } }
  }
```