# Next js | React - How to insert Google Ads in a page with dynamic content

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm fetching articles from an API, and then I parse the HTML code:

```
   function Article({ article }) {
      return (
        <PageContainer>
          <div className={styles.container}>
              {parser(article.content.html)}
          </div>
        </PageContainer>
      )
    ;
   }
```

My question is whats the best approach to insert a GoogleAdComponent when I get something like `<div class='google_ad'></div>` from the API?

I've tried adding a `useEffect`, check if there's a class with that name, then appendChild, but in React we need to create an element as a React Node and then add it to React.render() right?
I'm getting a feeling that there's an easier implementation, but I can't find any information online about this.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous. For example:

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

But never use it with user input, only with trusted origins

Comment: Thanks for responding :) How can I add a component dynamically to a specific line, with dangerouslySetInnerHTML ? The closest solution I've found was this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69039418/insert-google-adsense-after-3rd-paragraph

Comment: if you renders list and you need to add after 3 item just add new item in array with div with dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} like in react docs. Something like that at your link. Its depends on content which you show and how you show

Comment: for example you have array with objects. Add new string element. And add condition: if element is string - render with dangerouslySetInnerHTML